# BufferReader readLine() issue: not searching till end of the file

Tags: java

I am searching for a specific keyword inside in the file.and i want that it will print all the occurences of the file(count++).but it is printing only one occurence and also  printing  second occurence if keyword is present in the same line but it is not printing for all the keyword those are present in next lines.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class StringFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        double count = 0,countBuffer=0,countLine=0;
        String  lineNumber = "";
        String filePath = "C:\\IBM\\Project\\TestText.txt";
        String inputSearch = "public";
        String line = null;


          BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            //Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("filepath"));
            try {

                {
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null )

                {
                    countLine++;
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");
                    for (String word : words) 
                    {
                      if (word.equals(inputSearch)) 
                      {
                          System.out.println(word);
                        count++;
                        countBuffer++;
                      }
                    }

                    if(countBuffer > 0)
                    {
                        countBuffer = 0;
                        lineNumber += countLine + ",";
                    }

                }
                br.close();
                }      
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        System.out.println("Times foun`enter code here`d at--"+count);
        System.out.println("Word found at--"+lineNumber);
    }
    }
```

Output

```
public
public
Times found at--2.0//two times because both keyword are in same line
Word found at--3.0,//both keyword are in line no 3
```

but after line 3.0 it is not printing.

Thanks

Comment: Can you should a short example input file that this code doesn't handle well?  Also you should use `int` for your counters instead of doubles, but that isn't your problem here.

Comment: I've tried your code on my computer and it seems it is working fine...

Comment: Unrelated: Why are the 3 count variables `double`? Change to `int`. It's not like you can have half a count anyway, especially when the only change to them is a `++` operator.

Comment: Trace it. Maybe a character encoding (=data related) issue. Maybe a forgotten break in the original code. Code looks plausible.

Comment: I've tried your code on my computer too. The output looks correkt : Times foun`enter code here`d at--5.0 Word found at--1.0,2.0,4.0,. What is into your txt file?

Comment: It is printing only for one line after that it is not printing..but now i changed String[] words = line.split("\\s+"); and i got my answer

Comment: This alone can't make a difference. Splitting on individuals spaces would have given you more strings, but the actual words would be the same. Check again!

Comment: The code as posted is working correctly (apart from some strange usage of types). -1 for not posting a problem.

Comment: before I change it was printing only for one line and it was not going untill end of the file and now its working fine and printing all the occurences. Thnaks